# Python chainable class methods

Tags: python, class, methods, chaining, method-chaining

I want to do the following:

```
pattern = cl().a().b("test").c()
```

where `cl` is a class and `a, b, c` are class methods.

After that I need to call `pattern.to_string` and it should output a string that was formed. Each method returns a string.

Now how can I achieve the above? Append the method output to a list? What about the chainable function? If I wrote the class the normal way, the above won't work.

Thank.

Comment: What do you mean "the normal way"?  What have you tried so far, and in what way did it not work?

Comment: *“Each method returns a string”* – That’s not how that works.

Comment: @poke that's why I'm asking on stackoverflow. I wasn't exactly sure how should I implement chainable functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return the class instance at the end of each method and store the intermediate results in a class variable:

```
class MyClass:
    result = None

    def a(self):
        # do things and store in self.result
        self.result = ...
        return self

    def b(self, value):
        # do things and store in self.result
        self.result = ...
        return self
```

This allows you to chain the methods as desired: `cl().a().b("test").c()`.

You can then obtain the result by looking at the value of `instance.result`.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you!! I'll accept your solution when it's possible after 10 minutes.